# Run different color themes of two emacclients under the same server

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

I run the following commands to establish two clients under the same server

```
emacs --deamon
emacsclient  -c &> /dev/null &
emacsclient  -c &> /dev/null &
```

and want the two clients display different themes as:

[image]

It's very helpful since:

One client under leuven theme, focus on management with orgmode
the other under gruvbox theme, focus on implementing with editor

However,  I actually get this:

[image]

Multiple questions refer to the problems: 
[Different themes for terminal and graphical frames when using Emacs daemon - Emacs Stack Exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2096/different-themes-for-terminal-and-graphical-frames-when-using-emacs-daemon)

The problems with the solution:
1. the plugins were obsolete
2. they can solely change a  buffer rather than a frame.

Is it possible to get it done?